# ActionScript Vector casting inconsistency?

Tags: actionscript-3, vector, casting

When a Vector is casted like this...

```
var v1:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
v1.push("foo");

var v2:Vector.<Object> = Vector.<Object>(v1)

v1.push("bar");

trace(v1);   //foo,bar
trace(v2);  //foo
```

... a copy of the Vector is created, as you can see in the trace output.

But when you change line 3 to...

```
var v2:Vector.<*> = Vector.<*>(v1)
```

... no copy is created, both v1 and v2 point to the same object, trace outputs will both be "foo,bar".

Why that? Shouldn't there somehow be a consistent behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to realize is that `Vector.<Something>(Vector.<Anotherthing>)` is not a type cast. In fact, you can't cast a vector of one kind to a vector of another kind at all!  Try this:

```
var v1:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
var v2:Vector.<Object> = v1 as Vector.<Object>; // throws an error
```

You also can't assign a vector of subtypes:

```
var v1:Vector.<Object> = new Vector.<String>(); // throws an error
```

That is because while String is a subtype of Object, the two kinds of vectors are [*not related*.](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/ASC-3836)

So why doesn't your notation fail?  Because what you are really doing is calling the [top level function `Vector()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#Vector%28%29), which creates a vector from any collection type data you pass in.  The documentation for it says:

> If the sourceArray argument is already a `Vector.<T>` instance where T is the base type, the function returns that Vector. Otherwise, the result Vector is populated with the elements of the sourceArray Array or Vector.

The asterisk in your type declaration is a place holder, so the variable will hold any typed instance of Vector, and that allows for the function to return the same vector you passed in.

Comment: Ok, so it's more a syntax inconsistency. Looks like a typecast but is none. And there's an inconsistency in the top level Vector() function. Think it should always return a copy then. Thanks anyway! :)